# Bash needs resetting every time

Tags: bash

For some time my **bash is not showing what I write** ("echoing"?) and I have to run `reset` command every time I open new session.

I "fixed" it just by adding `reset` at the end of ~/.bashrc, but it is not the best solution since it's computer-specific garbage in my universal settings and this command takes time.

**What should I do to fix those settings permanently?**

Comment: Find out what makes your bash not echo.

Comment: Look for commands that output binary data to the terminal (in .profile, .bashrc, etc).

Comment: Check that your TERM environment variable is correct.

Comment: Use `script` to see if any weird characters are being sent by your prompt - use `vi typescript` to view the file, or `od`, don't use `cat`.

Comment: Removing .profile and .bashrc doesn't change anything. TERM is correct ('screen-bce'). I don't get the last one - i type "script" then "vi typescript" and it just opens vi.

Comment: Check the output of `stty`.  Then run `reset` and check `stty` again.  Note the differences.  One of the differences should tell you what's wrong.  If you can't see the output because the shell is borked, redirect it to a file like `stty > /tmp/sttyout`.

Comment: Good tip, I have this before resetting: "-brkint -imaxbel -icanon -echo" - the last one is responsible for lack of echoing. How to remove it?

Comment: Then do `stty echo`. Try to figure out where this comes from!

Comment: Have you been playing with configuration files in /etc?

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotally, this happens to me when I cat a binary by accident, for example. More generally, this can happen when something is writing ansi-control characters/sequences to the terminal and breaks it (I think). The causes are very environment dependent and figuring out why that happens on your machine does not fit very well to the Q/A format of stackoverflow. However, some people have provided clues as to how you could automatically reset your terminal.

There is no permanent workaround for it, but you could do something clever by defining e.g.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command
```

and in that...

if stty reports -echo, run stty echo.

```sh
PROMPT_COMMAND=zumba
zumba() { PS1="$: "; stty  | grep -qe -echo && stty echo; }
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if this can adversely affect your shell - like some non-interactive process breaking or some ncurses programs breaking.

Instead of the prompt command, You could also use the DEBUG-trap trick to run something before every command

See this: https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command